# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error everytime I try to get a random user

Tags: android, parse-platform

Problem: I want to match a current user with another user chosen randomly from the list. However, this is the error the logcat gives:

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 18, size is 5

   at package.packagename.FindingOpponentActivity$1.done(FindingOpponentActivity.java:190)
   at package.packagename.FindingOpponentActivity$1.done(FindingOpponentActivity.java:78)
```

the relevant lines, 190 and 78 respectively:

```
 while (rand > mUsers.size() && mUsers.get(rand).hasSameId(mCurrentUser)) {

   query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
```

The full code

```
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);


            if (e == null) {
                //success!
              public  List<ParseUser> mUsers = users;


       // case if there is just one user 

    else if (mUsers.size() >= 2) {

      int rand = (int)(Math.random()*20);
                    while (rand > mUsers.size() && mUsers.get(rand).hasSameId(mCurrentUser)) {
                        rand = (int)(Math.random()*20);
                    }
                    mOpponentRelation.add(mUsers.get(rand));

                    mOpponent = mUsers.get(rand);
                    mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I tried googling "how to get random user Parse android" but I was unable to find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (mUsers.size() >= 2) {
   Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(mUsers.size());
    while (mUsers.get(rand).hasSameId(mCurrentUser)) {
        rand = random.nextInt(mUsers.size());
    }
    mOpponentRelation.add(mUsers.get(rand));

    mOpponent = mUsers.get(rand);
    mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use %, will force random in the list size

one example in your code:

```
...
else if (mUsers.size() >= 2) {

int rand = Math.random()%(mUsers.size()-1) ;

...
```

if rand exceds size of users, you gain java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supposed to be `rand < mUsers.size()` in the while loop. not `>`!

Comment: Can you please explain your reasoning?  If I use while (rand < mUsers.size()), then the while loop will only execute IF the random number is less then the size of the list, which is not needed.

Comment: you will have to change your while condition. It is giving Arrayoutofbounds exception because if rand is greater than mUsers.size(), you are trying to pass mUsers an index that is greater than its size. In other words, you are trying to access something that is not in the array